# Sending emails in ASP.NET WebAPI app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on project which is using `ActionMailer` to send emails. This library is made for `asp.net mvc`, but currently we are moving project to `WebAPI`, so I'm looking for some best practices in implementation of email sending procedure. Can you suggest any approach?

Comment: Cant you just continue using ActionMailer? It is still .NET right?

Comment: Yes, its still .Net, but It was developed with MVC in mind. I'd like to know if there is any standart way to implement this in not MVC projects.